# Access ObjectiveC UIAlertController category in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uialertcontroller, bridging-header

`UIAlertController` category created in `ObjectiveC` like

**UIAlertController+CustomBlocks.h**

```
@interface UIAlertController (CustomBlocks)

+ (nullable instancetype)showAlertViewWithTitle:(nullable NSString *)title
                                        message:(nullable NSString *)message
                                        button1:(nullable NSString *)cancelButtonTitle;
```

To access in Swift file did bridging and imported category header:

**MyApp-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "UIAlertController+CustomBlocks.h"
```

in Swift file, not showing method to access. How to get it?

Thanks

Comment: I tried your code and it is working fine to me.  how are you accessing in Swift?

Comment: see how it looks in swift. 

     UIAlertController.showCustomAlertView(withTitle: <#T##String?#>, message: <#T##String?#>, button1: <#T##String?#>)

keep check the name of the file you added in the bridging header is correct.